# Convert array of Objects to 2d array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

How can I convert this `Array` of `Objects`

```
var tags= [
  {id: 0, name: "tag1", project: "p1", bu: "test"},
  {id: 1, name: "tag2", project: "p1", bu: "test"},
  {id: 2, name: "tag3", project: "p3", bu: "test"}
];
```

Into this 2d `array`:

```
[["tag1","p1", "test"],
["tag2","p1", "test"],
["tag3","p3", "test"]]
```

Comment: simple array.map https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `map`

```js
var tags= [ {id: 0, name: "tag1", project: "p1", bu: "test"}, {id: 1, name: "tag2", project: "p1", bu: "test"}, {id: 2, name: "tag3", project: "p3", bu: "test"} ];
var res=tags.map(o=>[o.name,o.project,o.bu])
console.log(res)
```

Or You could use a more generic approach

```js
var tags= [ {id: 0, name: "tag1", project: "p1", bu: "test"}, {id: 1, name: "tag2", project: "p1", bu: "test"}, {id: 2, name: "tag3", project: "p3", bu: "test"} ];
var res = tags.map(({id,...rest}) => Object.values(rest))
console.log(res)
```

Comment: I am getting an error: tags.map is not a function. This Array of Objects is retrieved from an API call and comes in the exact format I posted in the question above. If its not an array of objects is it just and object?

Comment: @Omiinahellcat yes in that case it's more than likely it's an object and not an object of type array

Answer (score 2):

If you want to conserve all properties you can use

```
let twoDArray = tags.map(tag => Object.values(tag))

// [[0, "tag1", "p1", "test"], [1, "tag2", "p1", "test"], [2, "tag3", "p3", "test"]]
```

Comment: ... or even `tags.map(Object.values)`.  But in either case, you'd have to ensure that all objects had their properties in the same order.

Comment: add running snippet. @khrzstoper

Comment: `.map(({id,...rest}) => Object.values(rest))` would be a bit closer to what OP has requested

Answer (score 2):

[Array.map](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-array-map-method/) will help you.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-array-map-method/

```js
var tags= [
  {id: 0, name: "tag1", project: "p1", bu: "test"},
  {id: 1, name: "tag2", project: "p1", bu: "test"},
  {id: 2, name: "tag3", project: "p3", bu: "test"}
];
          
   var newArr = tags.map(function(val, index){ 
            return [val.name,val.project,val.bu]
   }) 
          
   console.log(newArr)
```